# HTML space between buttons in table

Tags: html, css

I have created a table which contains two buttons in each of the rows and both of the buttons are jointed together, I want to seperate both of the buttons. I have used    which does does not work and css aswell, is their another way.

I have another problem as I dont want to display the action buttons inside table border, but outside it near the table.

```html
<table style="border:2px solid white; cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0">
    <tr style="background:#00B050;color:#fff;">
 
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Contact Renter</th>
        <th>Rent price</th>
  <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['productname'];?></td>
        <td><img src='./images/products/<?php echo $row["productimage"];?>' width='150' height='100' alt=''></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['productdescription'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rentersdetails'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rentprice'];?></td>
  <td>
     <input class="button_normal" type="button" value="Find Renter" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/maps/')"/>
  <input class="button_normal" type="button" value="Mail Renter" onclick="window.open('mailto:')"/>
  </td>   
    </tr>
<?php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if I understand correctly, you want the buttons to be "outside" of the table. You could do this by targeting the last `th` and `td` and remove borders and backgroundcolors (just hide the `th`). It will still be IN the table, but won't look like that.

In the below, edited snippet, you can see I've added some in-line styling. It's better to work with an external stylesheet, so be sure to target the right `th` and `input`! Check out [:nth-child()](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)-selector as a possible solution.

```html
<table style="border:2px solid white; cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0">
    <tr style="background:#00B050;color:#fff;">
 
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Contact Renter</th>
        <th>Rent price</th>
  <th style="display:none">Action</th>
    </tr>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['productname'];?></td>
        <td><img src='./images/products/<?php echo $row["productimage"];?>' width='150' height='100' alt=''></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['productdescription'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rentersdetails'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rentprice'];?></td>
  <td style="min-width:200px">
     <input class="button_normal" type="button" value="Find Renter" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/maps/')"/>
  <input style="margin-left:20px" class="button_normal" type="button" value="Mail Renter" onclick="window.open('mailto:')"/>
  </td>   
    </tr>
<?php
```

This is all fixed with very basic CSS, so if you have trouble with this, I would seriously consider following some CSS tutorials online!